# For Mozilla WebExtensions, how do I get Javascript errors to show up in the console log?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

For Mozilla WebExtensions, how do I get Javascript errors to show up in the console log?

I'm opening the developer tools for the appropriate tab. I run the
code below in a WebExtension content script.

```
"use strict"
console.log("Load start."); 
foofoofoo; // ***TEMP*** force error
```

The message "Load start." appears in the console for that tab, but there's no message for the error from the next line.  I never seem to get any Javascript error messages from add-ons in the console.  I can see them if I step through in the debugger, but can't just get an ordinary Javascript error message.

Comment: Firefox documentation says that the "Error console" is obsolete [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Error_console], but if I bring it up with CTL-SHIFT-J, the Javascript error messages appear.

Comment: DId you tryed looking at the browser's toolbox console? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox

Comment: Have you enabled display of JavaScript errors (drop-down in the DevTools on the left just above the area where the messages display. It's opened from "JS" in which you can select "Errors" and "Warnings")?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Google Chrome / Firefox do not see extension output in console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982)

Comment: Re "tryed looking at the browser's toolbox console?" Yes. Doesn't help.

Comment: Re "enabled display of JavaScript errors". Yes. Doesn't help. Only the global browser console, not the tab-local developer console, seems to get errors from content scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The "Browser console" (CTL-SHIFT-J) shows the Javascript error messages from a content script, but the Developer Tools console, even though it will show log messages from an add-on content script, does not.

This does not appear to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the browser console that you already discovered and the browser toolbox you can find addon-specific debuggers under `about:debugging`.

Which debugger to use for which context is documented on the MDN article [WebExtensions/Debugging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging)

Comment: Documented, but in a misleading way. "You'll see any output from console.log() statements in your content scripts. You will also see your content scripts listed in the Debugger, where you'll be able to set breakpoints, step through the code, and so on." Yes, you see those. But not Javascript errors from the content script.